# Install changeable registry values with vdproj Deployment Project

Tags: registry, vdproj

I wrote a vdproj Visual Studio Deployment Project and all is working fine, but there is one minor thing that annoys me.

I went to view - Registry to maintain some entries on the target machine. Specifically I'm writing some string values to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ourproduct....

All working perfectly. After installation the Registry values are there.

But my intention was to create these registry entries with initial values, but for the user to subsequently be able to modify those.

I find that every time I launch the software after installing it, it resets the values back to what they were when the software was installed.

How do I configure the .vdproj settings so that it doesn't do that?

Answer (score 0):

Ahhhhhh.... Never mind me. I'm being stupid. The registry entries only get reinstated when I rename the entries or remove them altogether. But if I change their content their changed content remains in place.